# Simple relational database between Sales and Item

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I am building a simple Point of Sale system for my project.
This system has a table named Sales and another table named Item.
In the Item table will have a column named itemcode which is a primary key.
In the Sales table will have a column named itemcode which is a foreign key referencing itemcode in the Item table.

The problem is should I make the itemcode in Sales table a foreign key referencing the itemcode in the Item table?

If it is a foreign key, I could not delete a particular item from the Item table if there were sales on this particular item. This is because there are foreign key in Sales table referencing the primary key in Item table.

If it is NOT a foreign key, the itemcode does not get updated when I update the itemcode in the Item table.

Any tips on resolving this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your item code will change for a given item over it's life in your database, then it is not a good candidate for being primary key. Under these circumstances, we usually generate auto-incrementing and appropriately arbitrary IDs to use as primary keys, and then use them in foreign key relationships. Have you cake and eat it, too... it just costs one more well-indexed and efficient column. :-)

Comment: Thanks, but how am I going to delete item from the Item table if that item is no longer available, but still need to maintain the records in the sales table?

Comment: To model it properly, you can do one of two things; either track inventory separately, or add a column to the item table which indicates availability, and use that column wherever you show items on the site (i.e. WHERE items.currently_available = TRUE)

Answer (score 0):

You can have an entity_id as the primary key of the item table and this will be referenced from sales table. The item code will be another column only in item table.

Comment: Thanks, but how am I going to delete item from the Item table if that item is no longer available, but still need to maintain the records in the sales table?

Comment: why dont you add a column quantity in item table, whenever an item is sold the value of quantity is decreased by 1. If dont have the item in your stock, the quantity field will have a value 0.
revert me back in case of any doubt